# How to restrict a particular command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have bash-3.2.tar.gz
I have all the tools needed to compile the bash. Now I need to restrict a command in the compiled bash binary, e.g. I want to restrict the command "kill" in the compiled bash binary. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would likely be much easier *before* you compile it.

Comment: `alias asdasd="echo bash: asdasd: command not found"`?

Comment: How is removing the kill command in any way useful?

Comment: Always remember that the user could spawn another shell, like `tcsh` or `dash` if they are installed, and that many languages also support `kill`, including C, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.  Many distributions will also have a `/bin/kill` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, so here are a few thoughts.

You can *remove* a command from bash before compiling it by editing the `DEFSRC` and `OFILES` variables in the `builtins/Makefile.in` (before running `configure`).

You can *disable* a built in command using the `enable` command.  For example, running `enable -n kill` would disable the builtin `kill` command, so that running `kill` would instead look for a file named `kill` in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I patched the bash package builtin kill.def to make it restricted:

```
--- builtins/kill.def.old       2016-09-14 14:13:49.058437000 +0530
+++ builtins/kill.def   2016-09-14 14:16:00.467550000 +0530
@@ -48,6 +48,7 @@
 #include "../bashintl.h"

 #include "../shell.h"
+#include "../flags.h"
 #include "../trap.h"
 #include "../jobs.h"
 #include "common.h"
@@ -79,6 +80,14 @@
   pid_t pid;
   intmax_t pid_value;

+#if defined (RESTRICTED_SHELL)
+  if (restricted)
+    {
+      sh_restricted ((char *)NULL);
+      return (EXECUTION_FAILURE);
+    }
+#endif /* RESTRICTED_SHELL */
+
   if (list == 0)
     {
       builtin_usage ();
```